# Designing WPF Windows for Free?

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

I'm starting a WPF project in a "free tools" environment. I'm currently working with the designer in Visual C# Express 2008, and directly with the XAML, both of which are very limited in design capabilities. My understanding is that Microsoft Expression Blend is not available for free (except for limited time trial).

Is Expression Blend expected to come out in a free Express version anytime soon? If not - are there any alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: I'm genuinely curious in what ways you find the VS designer limited. Personally, I would recommend against using a visual XAML designer at all - it is really much better suited for writing manually, much like HTML - and you'll get proper flexible layout that way, too. And as a code editor, VS2008 editor is usually sufficient,

Comment: I agree with Pavel. Write your XAML by hand. Forget the visual designer, it just creates stacks of redundant junk (in VS and blend).

Comment: I would have to disagree: the animation, templating, and data binding tools in Blend make it far superior.  Add in Behaviors, 3D, and Sketch Flow and Blend blows VS out of the water.  Yes, you can do plenty of good work in VS coding straight XAML, but an experienced Blend user can accomplish more work in less time.  

I also disagree about the redundant code: Blend's XAML output is very clean.  The only time it creates unnecessary code is when you set a property to a default value - in this case you should use the "Reset" feature to eliminate the unnecessary XAML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no free version of expression blend (apart from the time limited trial), and there hasn't been any announcement of anything planned.

Several useful tools are:

[Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/) and [XAMLpad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398.aspx) for testing blocks of XAML.

[StyleSnooper](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/02/wpf-tools-stylesnooper/) allows you to grab the default styles/templates from all the existing controls in the framework. Very useful if you just want to modify an existing style or template a litte.

Also, reflector has a [BAML](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins/Wiki/View.aspx?title=BamlViewer&referringTitle=Home) plugin available which can come in handy at times.

We have expression blend (as part of an MSDN subscription) and we barely use it. We used to use it for 2 things. 1) To grab styles, we now just use style snooper, it's easier. 2) For testing custom templates of complex controls like list views, we have now re factored the architecture slightly to generate test data when the XAML is being displayed in visual studio so we don't have to switch to blend all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I would only reccommend using Expression Blend if you are creating a very complex graphic or animation. For all other intents and purposes, stick with VS 2008. I have been studying WPF for about 3 months now, and I do not use anything other than Visual Studio. Even when I made a couple of games for my kids that had animations and the like, I didn't find the xaml editor to be at all limiting.

Of course, if you want a more light-weight xaml editor, check out [Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/). It's pretty efficient.