# Is there any way of getting a XAML Editor, either build or download?

Tags: wpf, xaml, components

In my current project (presentation, slide software) I need to be able to make some simple XAML, text images, movies and stuff like that.

If it were HTML I would go with fckeditor or another free editor, but what to do in XAML?

Anyone know if its possible to make one yourself (like executecommand to a IE)? or download one from anywhre on the net?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this question: [Designing WPF Windows for Free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211356/designing-wpf-windows-for-free)

The leading answer recommends [Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/), [XAMLpad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398.aspx) and several more options.